# Nuxt 2.5.0 + Firebase - dependencies were not found

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

I've been using firebase in Nuxt but with the 2.5.0 upgrade I'm getting these errors. Can't seem to figure out what the problem is?

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 7 errors                                                                           friendly-errors 13:21:54

These dependencies were not found:                                                                                friendly-errors 13:21:54
                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/array/find in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                                    friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/array/find-index in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                              friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/object/assign in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                                 friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/string/repeat in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                                 friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/string/starts-with in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                            friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/symbol in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                                        friendly-errors 13:21:54
* core-js/fn/symbol/iterator in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js                               friendly-errors 13:21:54
                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 13:21:54
To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/fn/array/find core-js/fn/array/find-index core-js/fn/object/assign core-js/fn/string/repeat core-js/fn/string/starts-with core-js/fn/symbol core-js/fn/symbol/iterator
```

Comment: wait for a hotfix in nuxt 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue should be fixed in nuxt 2.5.1 release.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.5.1

Comment: Getting even more dependencies errors now: * core-js/modules/es6.array.find in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/home/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 1 other

Comment: @ChrisF. delete node modules and lock file and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact problem.

```
* core-js/modules/es6.array.find in ./.nuxt/client.js                      friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator in ./.nuxt/client.js                  friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.date.to-string in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js
* core-js/modules/es6.function.name in ./.nuxt/client.js                   friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.object.assign in ./.nuxt/client.js                   friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.object.keys in ./.nuxt/client.js                     friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.object.to-string in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.promise in ./.nuxt/client.js                         friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor in ./.nuxt/utils.js               friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.match in ./.nuxt/client.js                    friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.search in ./.nuxt/utils.js                    friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-build-indicator.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.includes in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator in ./.nuxt/client.js                 friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.string.repeat in ./.nuxt/utils.js                    friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.string.starts-with in ./.nuxt/utils.js               friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es6.symbol in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/es7.array.includes in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/es7.object.get-own-property-descriptors in ./.nuxt/index.js
* core-js/modules/es7.promise.finally in ./.nuxt/client.js                 friendly-errors 20:39:58
* core-js/modules/es7.symbol.async-iterator in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
```

The thing is, I'm running nuxt 2.11.

Comment: I think it ended up being the package-lock.json file. Make sure you delete it and re-install.

Comment: firebase appears to use a different core-js version than cordova does by default. Version mismatch occurs and then this mess happens. Since cordova works with a webview, I instead enabled firebase in the webview rather than the native environment. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install core-js@2.6.10
```

fix the problem

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.10.3",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^5.0.7",
    "core-js": "2.6.10",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2"
  }
```